# PHP - Return array and use in a different php file

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question that I don't know how to solve. I read a lot of manuals, but didn't find the answer yet. So, I have 2 files, let's call file1.php and file2.php

On file1, I have this function:

```
function simpleQuery ($sql) {
    // Connects to my database, works fine.
    $conn = connect();

    if ($query = $conn->query($sql)) {
        $result = $query->fetch_all();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

On file2.php I want to loop using a for each on the variable returned by this function. On file 2, I have:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES";
    $array = simpleQuery($sql);

    foreach ($array as $ano) {
        echo $ano;
    }
?>
```

The problem is that my variable gets: "Array".
So, the echo above prints "Array" in the screen instead of the value that it should be printing.

It's a simple question, but I'm kinda (very) lost. Thanks!! :)

Comment: `print_r($ano)`

Answer (score 0):

If the array returned is key=>value style eg 'name'=>'kostas'

you loop foreach($myarray as $row){echo $row['name'];}

Answer (score -1):

Try using "POST" to send the value to the next page or alternatively try using